# The begining of Bitcoin

Tags: history

I want to ask, how was the first Bitcoin made? And how can it be made? Every time I think of Bitcoin, these questions come to my mind.

Comment: Pretty much the same way as all other Bitcoins have been made. I think you should make more clear what exactly you're not understanding about it.

Answer (score 0):

First bitcoin was created when the first block (and blockchain) was created.
Here is more important informations: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Genesis_block